# Using Qt signals and slots vs calling a method directly

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, class-design, signals-slots

Lets say I have a main window with a slider and a widget inside that window with a method called `setValue(int)`. I'd like to call this method every time the value of the slider has changed.

Is there any practical difference between the two following ways of achieving it:

## 1

```
void MainWindow::on_slider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    ui->widget->setValue(value);
}
```

## 2

```
// somewhere in constructor
connect(ui->slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), ui->widget, SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

For me the first approach looks better, because it possibly avoids some overhead related to signals and slots mechanism and also, allows me to process the `value` before sending it to `widget`, if there's a need for it.

Are there any scenarios where the second solution is better?

Comment: And how do you get `MainWindow::on_slider_valueChanged` called? Thats the point. Signals provide an abstraction of events and their handlers. Dont care about performance (atleast if it affects your design) if you dont have a bottleneck, especially not with GUI code. GUI code is absolutely not performance relevant.

Comment: @Paranaix: `MainWindow::on_slider_valueChanged` is called because `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()` automatically generates this connection. Performance is not my concern here, but the design is. I'm trying to find out why one is better than the other, if it makes any difference at all.

Comment: One definite advantage of the signals-and-slots method is that signal/slot connections are automatically and safely disconnected whenever either of their endpoints is deleted.  That means no risk of crashing due to access of a dangling pointer (e.g. if you did a "delete ui->widget" somewhere, your next call to on_slider_valueChanged() would crash, but example 2 would continue to run without errors)

Comment: The second approach is definitely better. In the first one, you introduce one more entity (on_slider_valueChanged) just to invoke some decent line of code. Moreover, those who will read your code are now have to scroll through all of micro-methods just to figure out the connections scheme.

Comment: In my opinion, it's the other way round. The second one is more direct - it connects directly signal with slot. The first one is indirect - you connect signal to your custom handler, which in turn invokes slot. First one doesn't "avoids some overhead related to signals and slots", on contrary, it adds some overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference, in your example, of using a signal instead of a direct call, is to allow more than one listener.

If you directly call your widget `setValue()`, then only that one widget will receive the C++ signal.

If you use a Qt signal, now any other object can connect to receive the event whenever it occurs.

If you do not foresee any other object to ever want to receive the value by signal, I would not bother with such. A direct call is definitively a lot faster (between 3 and 6 CPU instructions instead of dealing with strings to find receivers!), but as Paranaix mentioned, in a GUI it may not be much of an issue (although in this case it could become a problem on older computers if you send all those signals while moving the sliderbar.)

Comment: AFAIK the dealing with strings to find receivers happens only during the connect() and disconnect() calls, not during the emit-ing of the signals.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner And on Qt5 with new-style signal/slot connections, there's no dealing with strings at all :)

Comment: There is no direct call. Both cases use signal-slot connections.

Comment: There is a direct call, despite the fact that both cases use signal-slot mechanism.

Comment: You didn't mentioned the big advantage of the mechanism which is handling multithreading, so -1 from me. Dividing into GUI thread and Working thread is one of main purposes of signals&slots.

Answer (score 15):

Both approaches use signal-slot connections. In the first case, the `connect` call is made by `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()` called from `setupUi`. In the second case, you explicitly call `connect` yourself.

Also, the first approach is unnecessary in Qt5 when using C++11. You can modify the value in a lambda:

```
QObject::connect(ui->slider, &QAbstractSlider::valueChanged,
                 [this](int val){ ui->widget->setValue(val*2); });
```

To protect from deletion of `ui->widget`, you should use a `QPointer`:

```
class MyWindow : public QMainWindow {
  QPointer<QAbstractSlider> m_widget;
  ...
public:
  MyWindow(QWidget * parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ...
    setupUi(this);
    m_widget = ui->widget;
    QObject::connect(ui->slider, &QAbstractSlider::valueChanged, 
                    [this](int val)
    {
      if (!m_widget.isNull()) m_widget->setValue(val*2); 
    });
```

The overhead of signal-slot connections is [quantified in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10839370/1329652).

Comment: Sorry, your answer seems impressive but didn't you made a mistake on 'QPointer<QAbstractSlider>' ? I think it's rather a pointer on the inside of the window (on MyWindow?)

Comment: @kingsjester You're correct in that the pointer is owned by the instance of `MyWindow`. But it is a pointer *to* a `QAbstractSlider` that gets instantiated in `setupUi`. The pointer is type-safe - you couldn't make it point to a `QMainWindow` etc.

Answer (score 7):

Signal/slot advantages:

- multiple slots can be connected to single signal, and you don't bother with allocating and freeing memory for this
- you can handle multithreading with this

Signal/slot drawbacks:

- a little slower than direct call
- significantly slower if the slot is virtual
- QObject is rather heavy thing, so you usually try to avoid constructing billions of them

More details are available [here](http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work-part2-qt5.html)

Comment: + for mentioning multithreading. Slot might be invoked in different thread than signal and this is huge (maybe even best) advantage of this mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second method, since it happened that I forgot to delete the "auto-connect-slots" when the UI-element was removed, causing dead code. AFAIK it is the same "behind the scene" (look at the auto-generated qt-files).

When you would like to modify the value I would prefer following method:

```
connect(ui->slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(myOwnSlot(int)));

void MainWindow::myOwnSlot(int value) {
    /** do stuff */
    ui->widget->setValue(value);
}
```

Greetz

Answer (score 1):

Signals & Slots is a different coding style. You can do things with signals that can be useful and neat work arounds to traditional c++. For example you can emit const signals from const functions and have them connect to non const slots (where as in c++ you cannot make non const calls from a const function). I've never liked using mutable objects, so signals provide a clean work around for me.