# OpenMP, QTextEdit and QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, openmp

Well after trying everything i know and even by adding

```
QT_MainWindow::QT_MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::QT_MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qRegisterMetaType<QTextCursor>("QTextCursor");
    qRegisterMetaType<QTextBlock>("QTextBlock");
}
```

To my source i still can't modify the text from other Threads in both QTextEdit and QPlainTextEdit also i am using OpenMP with Qt.

can anyone tell me what is the correct way to modify text from other Threads in QTextEdit and QPlainTextEdit because i didn't manage to find anything about that to help me

Here is my source:

```
void QT_MainWindow::Load()
{
    ui->QT_PlainTextEdit->setPlainText("");

    std::ifstream file("File.txt");
    std::string line;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    while ( std::getline(file, line) )

    ui->QT_PlainTextEdit->appendPlainText( QString::fromStdString(line));

    file.close();
    }
}
```

I managed to get it work only like this

```
void QT_MainWindow::Load()
{
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_nested(3);
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
    {
      ui->QT_PlainTextEdit->setPlainText("");
    }
}
```

But if i try to set text

```
void QT_MainWindow::Load()
{
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_nested(3);
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
    {
      ui->QT_PlainTextEdit->setPlainText("TEST");
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x3bbc758), parent's thread is QThread(0x3bd140), current thread is QThread(0x3bbcb68)
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

also

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x465bfc0), parent's thread is QThread(0x3f3ad60), current thread is QThread(0x466d450)QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x465bfc0), parent's thread is QThread(0x3f3ad60), current thread is QThread(0x46eebe0)HEAP[app.exe]: 
Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 00000000023F0000, 0000000003F3DC40 )
```

Comment: it would be good to attach some source, it is difficult to say ...

Comment: Ok hold on i will in a bit

Comment: @RobertWadowski ok i added the source and note that i do the qRegisterMetaType before i run anything

Comment: If you want to load some strings from different thread I think you complicating live to yourself. It is better to put thread source in qthread and comunicate over signals/slots. It is not definietly QT way .... Create worker class, put it to thread, connect to ui slots and you have clear ( and separated ) implementation.

Comment: @RobertWadowski But what if i want to use OpenMP i really like to use it with Qt

Comment: std::ifstream file("File.txt");  std::string line; can be put in the thread btw, add logs to see if anything is read, these registermetatypes are needed when you are sending non qt type by signal. What result is ? I assume you reading non empty file.

Comment: @RobertWadowski do you like we move this to a chat?

Comment: @RobertWadowski ah ok np, the code just crashs idk everything is right i registertype after this line ui->setupUi(this);

Comment: @RobertWadowski well it all works fine if i don't use a thread but i really like to get the openmp to work

Comment: Any stack trace of crash ? On what it crashes ?

Comment: @RobertWadowski how i get that?

Comment: @RobertWadowski well my debugger not working i use win-builds.org

Comment: I strongly suggest usinq qtcreator, at this point I don't see how to help you.  Why do you have to use openmp ?

Comment: @RobertWadowski i like the options the lib gives me and its really good

Comment: @RobertWadowski also look at what i just posted and see why clearing the textbox works but appendPlainText wont work

Comment: I think I found reason see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501284/qt-updating-main-window-with-second-thread. It seems that only GUI thread can access ui and controls

Comment: @RobertWadowski take a look at that why i get that

Comment: Without debugger it will be guessing only. I belive setting empty string does not change object and because of that works. Try to setup environment for debugging, otherwise it will be difficult or impossible to solve this ...

Comment: @RobertWadowski i managed to get gdb from msys2 working what do i send you?

Comment: @RobertWadowski i just added the GDB's output

Comment: It is not safe to access GUI objects in a thread other than the GUI thread so this will not work. You can not use openmp for that at all.

Comment: @drescherjm so you are saying this is not possible using OpenMP?

Comment: Yes you can not use openmp this way with qt.

Comment: @drescherjm is there anyway i can use OpenMP with Qt to access GUI objects?

Comment: With signals and slots (via QueuedConnection) but then you will not have any performance benefit from the threads if the code is this simple.

Comment: @drescherjm can you provide an answer about how to do it please.

Comment: The link @RobertWadowski gave above explains this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501284/qt-updating-main-window-with-second-thread

Comment: @drescherjm ok so i wonder what to do with this question

Comment: I think it is a good question however maybe it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @drescherjm don't you think its better after i managed to fix it post it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are accessing Qt GUI object in a thread other than the main thread.

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html

> Although QObject is reentrant, the GUI classes, notably QWidget and
>   all its subclasses, are not reentrant. They can only be used from the
>   main thread.

One way around this is to use Qt signals / slots to connect a signal from your worker threads to a slot in your main thread using a QueuedConnection however in your case I do not see this making much sense. Even if you got the signal to work with openmp you will not be able to append strings in a parallel way to QPlainTextEdit that will improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Well i managed to do it and i think it must be a bit simpler than connecting slots.

in my qt_mainwindow.h i simply added

```
public slots:
    void QT_PlainTextEdit_appendPlainText(QString line);
    void QT_PlainTextEdit_SetText(QString line);
```

and in my qt_mainwindow.cpp i got this lines

```
void QT_MainWindow::QT_PlainTextEdit_appendPlainText(QString line)
{
    ui->QT_PlainTextEdit->appendPlainText(line);
}

void QT_MainWindow::QT_PlainTextEdit_SetText(QString line)
{
    ui->QT_PlainTextEdit->setPlainText(line);
}

void QT_MainWindow::Load()
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(1)
    {
        std::ifstream file("file.txt");
        std::string line;

        while ( std::getline(file, line) )
            QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this,"QT_PlainTextEdit_appendPlainText",Qt::QueuedConnection,Q_ARG(QString,QString::fromStdString(line)));
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Well i tried it as much possible and it didn't failed but i was wondering if i done it correctly

Comment: @drescherjm so what do you think about this?

Comment: better as for me, but I still think it should be done in qt way ( at least in my opinion )

Comment: @RobertWadowski so you say this is correct? i can't believe it

Comment: I am saying that is a better but not in qt way. You are using at least meta object system. I wrriten how I would do to load data using thread :)

Comment: @RobertWadowski ok i wonder why app go in to "not responding" state still

Comment: main thread eventloop is blocked. Thread where you loading file has not its own eventloop., QThread has ...

Comment: @RobertWadowski ok idk how to fix this can please help me with this

Comment: We are telling it since beggining. Use qthread class instead, connect signal slots :)

Comment: @RobertWadowski i know but i mean is there a way to fix it using this way?

Comment: @RobertWadowski ok i will also work on connect signal slots but i really wanted to be like only OpenMP  not involving QThread

Comment: @RobertWadowski this connect sinnal slots involves that i make a QThread and run my OpenMP thread in there right?

Comment: If you are using openmp with 1 thread is it even creating a thread at all?

Comment: Also for the case of creating QThreads I say it will take longer with additional threads than just executing in the main thread for the code you posted. marshalling the data has a time cost + the main thread needs to add the strings to the widget anyways. See the description of Queued Connections in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10839370/487892

Comment: @drescherjm I think it makes the thread since it was crashing and ok so you guys are saying that i don't use OpenMP at all?